# How to deal with unknown length input in x86 ASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu

So I have most of the code working, but I cannot figure out how exactly to deal with the fact that the input sentence is of an unknown length. I am new to assembly and this is all a bit confusing.

(Right now I have it set up as if the length were known to be three characters, but obviously I need to change that.)

```
.data       
input_msg:  .ascii "Enter a random sentence: "
input_msg_len:  .long 25
input_str:  .ascii  "???" # 3rd should get newline  
count:      .long 0 
newline:    .long 10    

.text               
.global _start          
_start:             

# prompt for input
    mov $4, %eax    # prompt for input
    mov $1, %ebx
    mov $input_msg, %ecx
    mov input_msg_len, %edx
    int $0x80
# get input
    mov $3, %eax    # 3 to request "read"
    mov $0, %ebx    # 0 is "console" (keyboard)
    mov $input_str, %ecx # input buffer addr
    mov $3, %edx    # number of symbols typed in
    int $0x80       # Go do the service!

again1:
    mov $input_str, %ecx    
    add count, %ecx # count is offset from input_str beginning

    mov $4, %eax    # to write
    mov $1, %ebx    # to console display
    mov $1, %edx    # 1 byte to write
    int $0x80   # Do it!

    push    %ecx        # push onto stack   

    incl    count   # increment count

    cmp $3, count   # compare lengths
    jnz again1     # jmp again if not 0 (no difference)

    mov $0, %edi    # use edi as loop counter

    mov $4, %eax    # print out msg
    mov $1, %ebx    # etc.
    mov $1, %edx    # length
    int $0x80       # OS, serve!

again2:     
    pop %ecx    

    mov $4, %eax    # print out msg
    mov $1, %ebx    # etc.
    mov $1, %edx    # length
    int $0x80       # OS, serve!        

    inc %edi    # increment edi 
    cmp count, %edi # compare lengths
    jnz again2  # jmp again if not 0 (no difference)

# print newline
    mov $4, %eax    # print out msg
    mov $1, %ebx    # etc.
    mov $newline, %ecx  # addr
    mov $1, %edx    # length
    int $0x80       # OS, serve!
# exit
    mov $1, %eax    # exit
    int $0x80       # OS, serve!
```

Basically, what I want to know is how do I get the code to work for any sentence rather than just one 3 characters long?

Comment: Null terminate the string. Or you need to store the length somewhere.

Comment: What is interrupt $80?  I think this was reserved for ROM basic. You will have to tell the environment your're programming in before anyone can help.

Comment: @Gene Int 80h is used by unix-like systems for system calls.  It is a bit like Int 21h under MS-DOS/Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to allocate a longer buffer for `input_str` and to read the amount of text effectively read-in, found in eax following the read syscall.

In other words, you need to decide on the maximum length you would accept and change the code to something like the following:
Note: it is ok to assign short strings like this, *statically*, of course if you needed a big buffer (say to get data from a file), you may instead allocate the buffer *dynamically*).  Again, for keyboard input 132 is probably adequate.

```
...
input_str:  db  132 dup(?)  # 132 bytes buffer for input string
input_str_len: .long        # length of the string effectively read from user
...
# get input
    mov $3, %eax    # 3 to request "read"
    mov $0, %ebx    # 0 is "console" (keyboard)
    mov $input_str, %ecx # input buffer addr
    mov $131, %edx    # _Max_ number of bytes accepted in input_str
    int $0x80       # Go do the service!

    move %eax, $input_str_len    # save nb of bytes effectively read
...
    #you can then use input_str_len to control when to exit processing loop etc.
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that? And how long do I make the buffer if I do not know how long the sentence is?

Comment: I couldn't get the  "db 132 dup(?)" part to work, but it did help me realize how to count the bytes, so thanks!

Comment: noob question, `mov %rax, $input_str_len` expressed in intel syntax? I get the message _"invalid combination of opcode and operands"_ when I write `mov input_str_len, rax`

Answer (score 0):

Well... you could do a sys_brk with `%ebx` = 0. That's your original "break" - save it. Add some multiple of 4k to that value and sys_brk again. Do your sys_read into that buffer. If you read the full 4k (in `%eax` after the sys_read), add some more to your current "break" and sys_brk again, then read some more... until done. This "should" give you everything in one contiguous buffer...

Heck of a lot easier just to decide on some "max" and don't let 'em enter any more than that! You may want to "flush the buffer". As you know, sys_read (from the keyboard) won't return until it sees a linefeed (0xA). If the pesky user has typed more than `%edx` characters, the remainder stays in the OS's buffer. You can see this in your 3-byte buffer code. Type "abcls". I think you'll find that the "ls" is read by your shell prompt after you exit, and gives you a directory listing. No problem, but it could be "rm" or something harmful! When your sys_read returns, if `%eax` is less than `%edx`, you're done. If `%eax` = `%edx` (it won't be more), if the last character in your buffer is LF (0xA), you're done. If not, sys_read into a dummy buffer until you do get that LF. This complicates your code a lot, but it's "safer"...

I could try an example in Nasm syntax, but I don't think I'd better attempt AT&T... :)

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused about what you are describing (my professor hasn't explained what any of the code represents really). I mean I get what you mean by making a max, but I don't think we are supposed to have a max. Then again the only description of what to do I am given is "This requires reading of a single character repeatedly in a loop, and push it onto the memory stack, until the "enter" key (newline character) is pressed. While in the loop, a counter (can use the edi register) counts how many letters that have been typed in so far." and I am not quite sure what he means.

Comment: I get that LF (0xA) is the "enter" newline thing. Though that gets me an error saying "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".